# Optimising postgres windows query

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx

I need some guidance with this query being too slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
  id,
  views - lead(views)
  OVER (PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY update_date DESC) vdiff
FROM videoupdate;
```

With 10 million+ rows it takes ~30 seconds. I have created a multicolumn index that reduced the original time from 1 minute.

I want to see difference between views for each row partitioned by id.

Some thoughts I had:

- After table update create TABLE AS with the query and select from it.
- Move old data to backup and shrink table.
- Look up data warehouse?
- Change database schema?

Hope I made myself clear. Thank you!

Comment: You should try to ask your question here instead https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: And also add the table definition (including indexes) and the resulting plan.